# WHy getting Firebase Quota exceeded error?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have cleared all cache on my browser still am getting this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Quota exceeded.
```

Comment: Share some code and specify the firebase product firing that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you've exceeded usage quota of Firebase.